# Using sheets as database and reference back and forth between sheets for a tournament setup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I would like to have 1 sheet with the following :

*sheet 1* : ( player database )

player name, teamname, memberid

*sheet 2* ( score & ranking )
player name, teamname, memberid, score round 1, score round 2, score round 3

**Want to have each row to select playername from dropdown box ( elements in dropdown is name of sheet 1), teamname and memberid should then be taken from the one they select from sheet 1 also automatically.**

*sheet 3,4,5* ( tournament setup, one sheet for each of 3 rounds) :

table 1: 
player1, player2, score player1, score player2
table 2:
player5,player6, score player5, score player6

**Here i would like to select players - from sheet 2 (not sheet 1 as sheet 2 represents the players that showed up and sheet one is all players possible ). but after the round i would like to put in the score for the 2 players, this score should be put into the correct position in sheet2.**

---

can this be done in excel ? im not very experienced in excel besides doing simple reporting so would love to get some examples of how this can be done if possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes based on what you have described this is possible in Excel:

Sheet2:

> - Want to have each row to select playername from dropdown box ( elements in dropdown is name of sheet 1 **Look at [Data Validation](http://www.excel-easy.com/basics/data-validation.html)**
> - Teamname and memberid should then be taken from the one they select
>   from sheet 1 also automatically **Look at [VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH formuale](http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/lookup-reference-functions.html)**

Sheets 3,4,5

> - Here I would like to select players - from sheet 2 **As Above, Data Validation**
> - after the round i would like to put in the score for the 2 players, this score should be put into the correct position in sheet2 **Look at the [SUMIF formula](http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/count-sum-functions.html#sumifs)**

Those three links should cover the majority of the functionality that you requrie. If you get stuck, post where you have got to.

Comment: got a long way with your links so will flag it as answer, might add some extras along the way. thanks.